# Filling in a web page with Delphi using TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, parsing, web

I use Delphi 7 on Vista.  So far, I have implemented a simple browser (using TWebBrowser) but I would like to automatically enter information when the web page asks for it. For example, I want to tell my app to go to Google, detect the Search field, enter a search phrase, and then click the Search button and then get the result.

Can someone shed some light on how this is done?

Comment: You need to give some more data. You're using a TWebBrowser? You want to auto-fill edit boxes that appear on the web-page?   It's better if you give an exact example (say, put some text in the page at google.com, and do a search etc).

Comment: [Populating a webform](http://delphi.about.com/od/twebbrowser/a/submit_web_form.htm)

Comment: Whiler-that looks like a reasonable answer - assuming Bill never updates his question...

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the DOM to do this. The best online resource for learning this in a Delphi setting is at [Brian Cryer's](http://cryer.co.uk/brian/delphi/twebbrowser/index.htm) site. Take a look at [How to read and write form elements](http://cryer.co.uk/brian/delphi/twebbrowser/read_write_form_elements.htm).

Answer (score 0):

In the google instance you could simply call the search URL directly yourself.

Eg. This URL searches for 'jam'

```
http://www.google.ie/search?q=jam&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari
```

Get your code to change jam for your search string and go to that URL. I hope this is what you are looking for.